# PHP preg_replace: Modify text within div of specific class

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm having a hard time trying to write a regular expression for the following scenario:

The string `$description` contains some text, as well as an embedded video somewhere within.

I need to modify an existing `preg_replace()` call to replace everything inside the `<div class="brightcove-player">` element, but I need to somehow grab the `videoPlayer` ID value from within.

I know people will recommend DOMdoc, but I really just need to modify the existing `regex` in the code.

See example below:

```
$description = '
    <p>Intro text.</p>
    <div class="brightcove-player" style="margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:8px;">
    <object id="time_brightcove_g161jf8dj271jd72jd82kf" class="BrightcoveExperience">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
    <param name="width" value="405" />
    <param name="height" value="228" />
    <param name="@videoPlayer" value="1234567890"/>
    <param name="isVid" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
    <param name="videoSmoothing" value="true"/>
    </object>
    </div>
    <p>End text.</p>
';

$output = '<p>Intro text.</p><div class="brightcove-player" style="margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:8px;"><a href="brightcove://1234567890">Watch this video<a></div><p>End text.</p>';
```

Comment: "I know people will recommend DOMdoc, but..." Tut tut tut! No buts! Continuing down the path you have now chosen you will most certainly end in tears. The slightest change in the 'source HTML' and you are, again, stuck with a regex problem.

Comment: Yes, there are easier ways. In particular [`qp(`](http://querypath.org/)`$html)->find("div[class=player] param[name=video]")->attr("value");`. But with enough expertise or [learning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) enthusiasm you could modify your existing regex. You should show what you have tried so far however.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: I figured out a workaround solution, but thanks for the input.

That qp() looks pretty cool, so I will definitely check that out when I'm not under the gun.